# Batch File If Statement Using Regex

Tags: regex, batch-file, if-statement

I have a batch file that first checks an outside file to see the source branch for the build then runs an `if` `else if` statement that runs regex to match the source branch which then determines where the build will deploy:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SEPARATOR=/
set filecontent=
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("BuildBranch.txt") do (
  set currentline=%%a
  set filecontent=!filecontent!%SEPARATOR%!currentline!
)

echo %filecontent%

If NOT "%filecontent%"=="develop(.*)" (
    echo Deploying to dev DEVELOP
) else If NOT "%filecontent%"=="^.feature(.*)" (
    echo Deploying to dev FEATURE
) else If NOT "%filecontent%"=="master(.*)" (
    echo Deploying to integration MASTER
) else If NOT "%filecontent%"=="^.hotfix(.*)" (
    echo Deploying to integration HOTFIX
)

pause
```

I have run each of the regex's through the regex101 site but there may still be issues with them. My main issue is that ever time I run my batch file it only runs the first of the `If statements`. The variable `%filecontent%` is `feature/MyNewFeature` so it should see that it doesn't match the first if statement and go on to the second statement. I don't know if this is an issue with my regex or my `if statements`.

Comment: What shell do you use? CMD does not have "use regex to match" feature... (`if /?` to get help)

Comment: Ah that would probably be why the regex isn't working to well then, with my build I use Powershell. I guess I would need to use powershell first to do the regex then.

Answer (score 4):

The `IF` does not support *regex* matching. But you could try some workaround like the following:

```
echo %filecontent% | >nul findstr /i /r /c:"develop.*" || ( echo Deploying to dev DEVELOP )
echo %filecontent% | >nul findstr /i /r /c:"^.feature.*" || ( echo Deploying to dev FEATURE )
echo %filecontent% | >nul findstr /i /r /c:"master.*" || ( echo Deploying to dev MASTER )
echo %filecontent% | >nul findstr /i /r /c:"^.hotfix.*" || ( echo Deploying to dev HOTFIX )
```

From there you could build around the [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command, since it can match some *regex* (not advanced ones thou), in conjunction with the `||` operator, for cases of `if NOT`, or the `&&` operator, for cases of `if`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You missed the `^` at the `.feature.*` string; and since there is `if NOT` in the question, you should use `||` instead of `&&`... anyway, great approach!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Edited it!